# How to remove duplicates from a read and split text file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a block of text in a .txt file and I want to remove duplicate words from it, then read each word individually. Is there a way I can remove duplicate words while still conforming to the below code:

```
TEXT = "./text.txt";
dictionary = open(TEXT, "rt").read().split();
```

Thanks

Comment: How is the text formatted? Is it one word per a line?

Comment: No, it's in paragraphs.

Comment: For your future self and those who you collaborate with using python, please consider removing the terminating semicolons from your code. :)

Comment: Could you give an example input and a desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing that your code works correctly so far, only that it keeps duplicates, then you can use:

```
with open(TEXT, 'rt') as f:
    dictionary = set(f.read().split())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = set(f.read().split())

>>> for k in s:
...     print k
...
```

Use a set

```
 |  set() -> new empty set object
 |  set(iterable) -> new set object
 |  
 |  Build an unordered collection of unique elements.
```